# How do OpenId Connect's id token feed into a subsequent OAuth2 flow for authorizing access on another resource?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

Assume aim is to authorize access to Resource Server (RS) resource.com/resource via access token but using OpenId Connect for authentication instead of relying on custom authentication integrations of Authorization Server available in OAuth2.

I am not clear how they interoperate, how does the id token feed into subsequent OAuth2 flows in particular.

1.OpenId Connect is implemented as an OAuth2 "authorize access to user profile/identity", but what flow does it use for it?. At this point, The requester (user agent or client app) gets id token and access token to userInfo.

2.But now, identity obtained, an authorization/access token to end service (Resource Server RS) is needed.
What is the next step until the end goal of access token to Resource Server?

Here we have another OAuth2 flow, so that based on identity of user and client the end access token is obtained. I do not have the details of this. I saw detailed presentations of OpenId connect up to the point of having the id token and access token to userInfo and detailed presentation of OAuth2 flows all 4 of them, but never saw an end to end concatenation of these protocols, is there such an integration?

Does the requester send the id token to authorization server together with the request for code or access token directly (depending on the flow)? I never saw an end to end flow, can you indicate a video or text description of it?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, client applications don't send ID tokens to authorization servers. (In the specification, there is a request parameter `id_token_hint`. But, it should be ignored here to avoid confusion.)

Normally, resource servers require only access tokens. Client applications don't have to send ID tokens to resource servers.

Reading "[Diagrams of All The OpenID Connect Flows](https://medium.com/@darutk/diagrams-of-all-the-openid-connect-flows-6968e3990660)" may help you.